# Angularjs ng-if with ajax request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angular-ng-if, angularjs-ng-if

I'm new to angularjs and trying to figure out how to show/hide navbar elements depending on permissions. I'm currently getting the permissions via an ajax request:

```
mycloudControllers.controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/api/header').then(function(data) {
            $scope = data.data;
            console.log($scope);
        });
    }
]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-if="viewFiles || updateFiles" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
```

JSON Response (console.log):

```
{viewAccounts: true, viewAccountTypes: true, viewFiles: true, updateFiles: true}
```

The console logs the correct permissions (set to true) but I can't figure out how to get the compiler to wait until the request finishes to execute the ng-if. I want to use ng-if so the DOM elements are completely removed as opposed to just hidden.

I may be going about this the wrong way, so any light that can be shed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are overwriting the entire scope. Try defining a property on it: $scope.permissions = data.data

Comment: @marko add yours as an answer and I'll mark it. That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the entire scope. Try defining a property on it:

```
$scope.permissions = data.data
```